# Firebase AuthUI not triggering callback function with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, ios15

I recently updated an app I'm working on to IOS15 and I've hit a snag while testing.

When the user tries to log into the app using FirebaseUI (with google or email) the login process completes but does not trigger the callback function `didSignInWith:` from the delegate.

None of the print statements are being called from this class, but if I restart the app it behaves as if login was successful

Does anybody know what I've done wrong here?... as far as I can tell everything should work fine

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseUI

class LoginViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, FUIAuthDelegate {
    
    let imageView: UIImageView
    let title: UILabel
    let text: UILabel
    var parent: WelcomeViewController? = nil
    var authUI: FUIAuth
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        
        
        authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        
        let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [FUIGoogleAuth(authUI: authUI), FUIEmailAuth()
        ]
        authUI.providers = providers
        
        
        authUI.delegate = self
        
        let loginButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 50))
        loginButton.backgroundColor = .blue
          loginButton.setTitle("Let's Get Started!", for: .normal)
          loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        loginButton.center = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: ((frame.height/4) * 3) + 50)
        addSubview(loginButton)
    }
    
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        let authViewController = authUI.authViewController()
        parent?.present(authViewController  , animated: true, completion:  nil)
        
    }

    //MARK: Authentication Delegate
    
    func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?) {
      // handle user and error as necessary
        print("Login attempted")
        if( error != nil){
            print("Error Logging In \(String(describing: error))")
        }else{
            userHandler.doesUserExist({(exists: Bool) in
                if(exists){
                    self.parent?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }else{
                    let manager = UserManagerViewController()
                    manager.shouldCreateUser = true
                    let nvc = CalendarNavigationController(rootViewController: manager)
                    self.parent?.present(nvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })
        }
    }
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        let sourceApplication = options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String?
      if FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.handleOpen(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication) ?? false {
          print("Think did log in successful")
        return true
      }
      // other URL handling goes here.
        print("think did not log in")
      return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your cell still displayed when the callback should get called ? If not then here's the problem :

Your cell object **can be deallocated** (managed by the UICollectionView), and it happens that it's also the delegate for firebase. When that happens, firebase call a delegate that is nil, and it does nothing.

What you can do is create a specific class that will conform to the delegate protocol, keep a strong reference to it in a controller or viewModel that won't be terminated unless you want it (here the controller of viewModel is the object that initialize the cell), pass it as a dependency to the cell object (dependency injection), and set it as the authUI.delegate. If you follow these instructions the delegate will be retained cause it has a strong reference.

Comment: the ui sits onto of the cell (one of those "swipe down to dismiss" modals), I wonder if the CollectionView is deallocating the cell while the modal is open and recreating it when the modal is closed... but after the callback should be triggered..... because the button is visible when the modal dismisses (I'm now learning how to make strong references - which I did not know was a thing until now)